# What is an actual absolutely pedantically rigorous proof that there is no $f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0+b_1/x+...+b_m/x^m$ with $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Spivak's Calculus: Chapter 10, problem 22c:

> Is there a function
> $$f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0+\frac{b_1}{x}+...+\frac{b_m}{x^m}$$
>
> such that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?

We can write $f$ as

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}g_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}h_i(x)$$

where

$$g_i(x)=a_ix^i$$
$$h_i(x)=\frac{b_i}{x^i}$$

Then

$$f'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}g_i'(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{m}h_i'(x)$$

$$g_i'(x)=a_i i x^{i-1}, i=1,...,n$$
$$g_0'(x)=0$$
$$h_i'(x)=\frac{-b_i}{x_i^{i+1}}, i=1,2,...,m$$

Thus, none of the terms in $f'(x)$ contains $x^{-1}$.

This is the proof contained in the solution manual to Spivak's Calculus.

However, how do we know that the sum of two or more terms doesn't generate $x^{-1}$?

The proof above seems relatively incomplete or informal. What is an actual absolutely pedantically rigorous proof that there is no such $f$ with $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: This basically boils down to the assertion that two polynomials that take the same values everywhere must be the same polynomial (same degree and same coefficients of each power of $x$), which itself boils down to the statement that a polynomial that is equal to $0$ everywhere must be the obvious constant polynomial.

Comment: No such $f$ such $f'(x)=1/x$ but on which interval ? If I take interval $(0, +\infty)$ there if evidently (without pedantry...) the natural logarithm function $\ln$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Note that the body of the question specifies the form of potential antiderivative being considered.

Comment: @Noah Schweber You are right. I was just wondering why the log function hasn't been mentionned.

Comment: @JeanMarie This is from chapter 10 "Differentiation" from Spivak's Calculus. Logarithms have not appeared yet, and only appear in a chapter much later on.

Comment: @GregMartin to which two polynomials would we apply your assertion? $f(x)$ as defined above is one; is $x^{-1}$ considered a polynomial?

Comment: No, but the argument can be applied to $x^mf(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

One possible choice for $f$ is such that $f(1) = 0$, namely
$$f(x) = \int_1^x \frac{dt}t$$
for $x > 0$. It is easy to show that $f$ satisfies the functional equation
$$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$$
by using $\int_1^{xy}=\int_1^x + \int_x^{xy}$.

Now let $f$ be of the assumed form, and let $h[f]$ denote the index of the highest-degree term, and $\ell[f]$ the index of the lowest-degree term. In your notation this reads $h[f] = n$ and $\ell[f]=m$.

The functional equation means in particular $$f(x^2)=2f(x)$$ and therefore
$$h[f(x^2)] = 2n = h[f(x)] = n$$
so that $n = 0$.  A similar argument holds for $\ell$ so that we can conclude
$$f = \text{const.}$$
which can obviously not be.

Using different offsets for $f$ (i.e. chosing lower value other than 1 for the integral) won't fix this.

---

**Note:** By the very definition of $f$ it is clear that $f$ is not well defined for arguments $x\leqslant 0$, thus it is clear that expanding $f$ around 0 is problematic at least.  A much more interesting result would be to conclude that no finite expansion point will do. (The usual expansion point for $\ln$ is 1.

Comment: Since we want the derivative to be $\frac{1}{x}$, we define $f$ as the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$. Since $f$ obeys the functional equation, it obeys the particular case $f(x^2)=2f(x)$. At this point you assume that each side of this equation is a polynomial, and you define a notation for highest and lowest degree terms. One question here: the lowest-degree term in the polynomial proposed in my question is not $m$, as you wrote? If indeed both sides are polynomials arising from the integral you proposed, then a contradiction follows. Hence, if $f$ is this integral, then it cannot be polynomial.

Comment: @evianpring: I did not assume it's a polynomial, just that it has the form as assumed in the question.  Namely, that it has finitely many terms of the form $a_m x^m$ where $m$ might also be negative.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to establish uniqueness of coefficients of polynomials, and hence of 'Laurent polynomials', meaning a polynomial in $x$ plus a polynomial in $\frac{1}{x}$. Here is a 2-step process for proving it.

> **Theorem. (Uniqueness of Polynomial Coefficients)**
>
> Let $\phi,\psi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be two given polynomial functions defined as  $\phi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ and $\psi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k$, where $n\geq 0$ is an integer and $a_k,b_k\in\Bbb{R}$ (possibly zero). If $\phi=\psi$, then for each $k\in\{0,\dots, n\}$, we have $a_k=b_k$.
>
> **Corollary. (Uniqueness of 'Laurent Polynomial' Coefficients)**
>
> Let $f,g:\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{R}$ be two Laurent polynomials with real coefficients, meaning $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=-n}^na_kx^k$ and $g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=-n}^nb_kx^k$ for some integer $n\geq 0$ and $a_k,b_k\in\Bbb{R}$. If $f=g$, then for all $k\in\{-n,\dots, n\}$, we have $a_k=b_k$.

What's the proof of the theorem? Very simple. Since $\phi=\psi$ by hypothesis, we have $a_0=\phi(0)=\psi(0)=b_0$. Next, $\phi=\psi\implies \phi'=\psi'$ as functions, so we have $a_1=\phi'(0)=\psi'(0)=b_1$. And so on: for each $k$, we have $\phi^{(k)}=\psi^{(k)}$, so $a_k=\frac{\phi^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=\frac{\psi^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=b_k$. This proves uniqueness of coefficients of polynomial functions. This is an idea you'll definitely encounter in the later chapters on Taylor polynomials, but you do not need to have heard of them at all to understand this proof; it is a basic exercise in differentiating polynomials.

The corollary follows immediately from this. Given $f,g$, we consider $\phi(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}a_{k}x^{k+n}$ and $\psi(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^nb_kx^{k+n}$ (I essentially multiplied everything by $x^n$). These are now polynomials, and since $f=g$ on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, it easily follows $\phi=\psi$ on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and hence by continuity they're equal at the origin as well, so $\phi=\psi$ on all of $\Bbb{R}$, and hence by the theorem, their coefficients are equal.

To relate these results to your question, you suppose for the sake of contradiction there exists $f:I=\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in I$, we have  $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, and such that
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^na_kx^k=\sum_{k=-n}^{-1}a_kx^k + a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^na_kx^k.
\end{align}
Note, we split the sum into three parts: those with negative powers of $x$, the constant term, and those with positive powers of $x$. Calculate the derivative:
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\sum_{k=-n}^{-1}ka_kx^{k-1}+ 0 +\sum_{k=1}^nka_kx^{k-1}
\end{align}
None of these terms contains a multiple of $\frac{1}{x}$, so by uniqueness of the coefficients (the Corollary above), it is not true that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, so it is a contradiction (you may want to write things out without the $\sum$ notation to see the various terms).

Answer (score 0):

It $f'(x)=1/x$ on $\mathbb R^+$ then $f(x)=\int_1^x dr/r=\ln x$.

If $n>0,\,a_n\neq0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}[f(x)/\ln x]=\infty$.

If $m>0,\,b_m\neq0$ then $\lim_{x\to0^+}[f(x)/\ln x]=\infty$.

Hence all $a_i,b_i=0 $ except possibly $a_0$.
Thus $f$ is a constant.
But then $f'(x)=0\neq1/x$, still a contradiction.
Thus $f(x)$ cannot be written in that form.